# How to keep php session alive on in iframe on mobile devices (e.q. iPhone)

Tags: php, session, iframe, mobile

Situation:

- I have 2 websites; dealer.nl and user.nl
- On user.nl I include a i-frame from dealer.nl, which is basically a compact webshop
- Dealer.nl sets some sessions vars, if I echo them I see them filled correctly
- When I now visit another page on my iPhone in my i-frame the session seems destroyed, vars are lost

I looked it up and found out that mobile devices (e.q. safari on iPhone) do not allow third party sessions to run. But I haven't yet found a solution for this.

All is working well on computer browsers.

Anyone that can help me out?